# Get Color Palette of Image using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, colors, color-palette

I am trying to get the `Color Palette` of an image. I tried various methods, and now I use the following code in `PowerShell`, but I could not get the correct result:

```
$filename = "C:\Users\schoo\Desktop\bb.jpg"
$BitMap = [System.Drawing.Bitmap]::FromFile((Get-Item $filename).fullname) 

Foreach($y in (1..($BitMap.Height-1))){ 

  Foreach($x in (1..($BitMap.Width-1))){ 

         $Pixel = $BitMap.GetPixel($X,$Y)         
         $BackGround = $Pixel.Name
         }

$R = $Pixel | select -ExpandProperty R
$G = $Pixel | select -ExpandProperty G
$B = $Pixel | select -ExpandProperty B
$A = $Pixel | select -ExpandProperty A

$allClr = "$R" + "." + "$G" + "." + "$B" + "." + "$A"
$allClr  
}
```

The result take me more than thousand `RGB` codes:
[image: wrong result]

Comment: What's the correct result that you want to get?

Comment: I want to get Color Palette of that image, which very small data result of colors, it will maybe 5-10 RGB in the result. please see this result: bit.ly/2xo7cuB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that by "color palette" you mean the swathe of *distinct* colours that appear in the image.

A simple (and quite fast) way to select only a distinct subset of a collection is to use a hashtable.

```
$filename =  'C:\Users\schoo\Desktop\bb.jpg'
$BitMap = [System.Drawing.Bitmap]::FromFile((Resolve-Path $filename).ProviderPath)

# A hashtable to keep track of the colors we've encountered
$table = @{}
foreach($h in 1..$BitMap.Height){
  foreach($w in 1..$BitMap.Width) {
    # Assign a value to the current Color key
    $table[$BitMap.GetPixel($w - 1,$h - 1)] = $true
  }
}

# The hashtable keys is out palette
$palette = $table.Keys
```

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen - I want to get Color Palette of that image, which very small data result of colors, it will maybe 5-10 RGB in the result. please see this result: bit.ly/2xo7cuB. your code is always get error for me.

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen - I fixed, thank you. just change $ht to $table. but that's not answer my q, please look my previous comment.

Comment: Eh, if you want the result that TinEye's proprietary API gives you, then you'll have to use their API

Comment: Sir can you fix some thing for me?, in the hash table can give all color names: $table.Keys.name - but the color names is not HEX value for web, I  want to get all Hex values. thank you

Comment: `$Table.Keys |%{ '0x{0}' -f $_.Name }`

Comment: It shows some thing like 0xffced02f - I want to get ced02f which is the web color. please can you fix it for me?

Comment: `$Table.Keys |%{ '0x{0}' -f $_.Name.Substring(2) }`

Comment: oh, thank you. $Table.Keys |%{"#" + $_.Name.Substring(2) }. i appreciate you.