# filter black and white photo's with powershell

Tags: powershell

For my job we process sometimes a few thousand of photo's. But only photo's with text (scanned files for example) are important to us, so we only want pictures with black and white (and maybe slight variants on black).

This is in essence a way to filter the photo's before we are letting our ocr tools loose on them.

So after some googling around, I figured I'd need to calculate the RGB value from every pixel inside a picture, with some variation on "pure" white and "pure" black.

I've found: [Get Color Palette of Image using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46614133/get-color-palette-of-image-using-powershell)

but no idea on how to proceed and get to the point where i can say: this image consists of mostly white and black pixels.

So in short:

1. get a 2-dimensional table with a rgb value for every pixel
2. calculate how much pixels are white/black and if more then x % is white, it's good, if any other color appears it's bad.

Comment: Black, white (and shades of grey) have very low saturation, so you could use **ImageMagick** (as a one-liner) to get the mean, or peak saturation and see if that exceeds a low threshold.

Comment: it seems thats mostly used to convert files? Not to filter them? Or am i wrong in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Black, white (and shades of grey) are characterised by very low saturation, so you could use **ImageMagick** (as a one-liner) to get the mean, or peak saturation and see if that exceeds a low threshold.

Let's say your image is called `image.jpg`, this will tell you the mean saturation of the image - expressed as a number between 0 (pure black and white) and 100 (fully saturated colour):

```
convert image.jpg -colorspace HSL -channel S -separate -format "%[fx:int(100*mean)]" info:
```

So, if I make a saturated blue image:

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:blue blue.jpg
```

[image]

and test it, I get 100:

```
convert blue.jpg -colorspace HSL -channel S -separate -format "%[fx:int(100*mean)]" info:
100
```

Whereas if I make a black-white gradient:

```
convert-size 100x100 gradient:black-white  gradient.jpg
```

[image]

and test it, I get zero saturation (no colour):

```
convert gradient.jpg -colorspace HSL -channel S -separate -format "%[fx:int(100*mean)]" info:
0
```

---

You can read the **ImageMagick** command like this... *"Open the input image and convert it into Hue, Saturation and Lightness instead of RGB. Select the the Saturation channel and separate that out - discarding Hue and Lightness. Then tell me the mean value of that channel scaled to an integer in the range 0-100."*

---

If you install v7 or better of **ImageMagick**, change the word `convert` to `magick` in the command - or tick the box marked *"Install legacy tool versions"* when installing.

Comment: does it actually convert the original image or is this a temporary convertion without altering the original image?

Comment: It only reads the original image - without changing or writing to your disk.

Comment: allrighty, final question:  when i execute the command like you do, i get as result both the "info:x" value and the conversion value. How do i filter to get only the conversion value?

Comment: Probably something to do with Windows’s awful quoting. Maybe try putting a caret (`^`) before the `%` sign? Or a second `%` sign?

Comment: nope, tried about every variation i could think off, even checked the imagemagick page, on the format and it seems ok, but i still get 2 results

Comment: Can you show a screen grab of the command you used and the error?

Comment: Ugh! Looks like a stray linefeed character maybe. Try changing format to `"%[fx:int(100*mean)]\r\n"

Comment: nope, thats worse, it's missing a terminator now.  It doesn't have anything to do with me copy paste'ing your solution or something?

Comment: There is no -channel S. ImageMagick uses -channel green or -channel g for the second channel of HSL or -channel 1. See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#channel

Comment: @fmw42 I had `G` in there originally but found `S` worked the same on my system.

Comment: `@Mark Setchell`, It is news to me that ImageMagick allows such notation. It is not documented. Perhaps you are actually reading the first channel, Hue, by mistake. I doubt that ImageMagick allows any arbitrary letter corresponding to every colorspace. What would it do for YCbCr for the second channel. If you separate all channels of your gradient HSL, you will see that the first two channels are both black (Hue and Saturation) and only the Lightness channel shows the gradient. So, yes, you are just getting the mean of the first channel (hue). That is expected as hue for black is 0.

Comment: @fmw42 `convert xc:"rgb(67,68,90)" -colorspace HSL -channel S -separate txt:` gives 14% same as https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_converter.asp

Comment: whether it is channel S or channel G, i still can't get the command to only answer the value without repeating the value i'm comparing it to. I tested replacing channel S with G, i got the same result.

Comment: `@Michael` What is your ImageMagick version. (convert -version). And have you tried in your CMD window rather than in Powershell? Can you post a link to your input image? I suppose it is possible but undocumented that ImageMagick allows HSL or HSB letters for the channels, since it is a recognized colorspace. But it is then undocumented. I can confirm your result of 15% for -channel S. But I would not rely upon it for all colorspaces.

Comment: Sorry, I really don’t know much about Windows. Your commandline version seems to work correctly, so I am guessing something needs quoting in Powershell. Maybe try replacing the double quotes in the format string with single quotes, or try just `”%mean”` and get a number between 0 and 1 rather than 0 and 100.

Comment: sry for the late responce: the correct syntax is: magick "C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\cmMFbdH.jpg" -colorspace HSL -channel G -separate -format "%[fx:int(100*mean)]\r\n" info:         so without the numbers after the info: